# Reading DICOM file formats

Tags: dicom, evil-dicom

I have used Evil DICOM library to read a DICOM file.It is displaying the Raw DICOM file correctly but it is not displaying the other formats.Plz suggest me solution or suggest me any other C# library which reads all the formats correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about DICOM files with compressed images. You can access the fragments in the pixel data element and uncompress them yourself in [Evil Dicom](http://evildicom.rexcardan.com):

```
DicomFile df = new DicomFile("compressed.dcm");
Fragment[] frags = df.PixelData.Fragments;
```

but obviously this is more complicated than you probably want. I will try to get the CompressionHelper class running within the next few versions. Many compression formats are proprietary and code for decompression is hard to find.

I believe [Grassroots DICOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcm/) may be what you are looking for. Not as easy as Evil Dicom, but it supports the formats you want.

Comment: Hello,  Can you please help me understand how can I interpret DICOM filenames? I mean I have a DICOM file whose series id is like "1.3.6.1.4.1.9590.100.1.2.378287575512351991512183998933310507019". How can I interpret this? I referred the link where they talk about DICOM tags but how to understand what series is this?